# (c++) std::make_unique<something>

Tags: c++, string, class, polymorphism, unique-ptr

got a little problem on a code like this:

An abstract sensor class (i use polymorphism):

```cpp
class Sensor //abstract class
{
    public:
    Sensor(int id, std::string name):id_{id},name_{name}{}

    private
    int id_;
    std::string name_;
}
```

A temperature sensor to implement the sensor class (this can be any sensor possible (pressure, acceleration... but i needed an example).

```cpp
class Temperature : public Sensor
{
    public:
    Temperature (int id, std::string name):Sensor{id, name}
    ~Temperature(){}
};
```

The main code:

```cpp
std::string sensor = "Temperature"; 
//but sometimes this is the name of another sensor "Pressure" or "Speed" for example

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sensor>> sensorList

sensorList.push_back(std::make_unique<sensor>(01, "test"));
```

The problem is with the `sensor.push_back(std::make_unique<sensor>(01, "test"));` line, i can't know what will be in `std::string sensor`, excepted the fact this is exactly the string i would write to call the corresponding sensor(for exemple, to create a temperature sensor, i will need `std::make_unique<Temperature>(01, "test")`, so i write: `std::string sensor = Temperature`).

How can i code this, because i can't code a bunch of if conditions, because sensors will be added/removed later in the program, and i don't know which ones.

Have a nice day

Timtanium

Comment: When you  can't know at the constructor level, you have to design a run time method. See how windows implements that (with COM) in which all objects start from a common base (IUnknown) then later they can be queried.

Comment: "sensors will be added/removed later in the program, and i don't know which ones." How, exactly, will you find out at runtime?

Comment: All my sensors are on a .txt file (name, id), and i read this file to create all the sensors on the list.
So i have my sensor name id and their class name in 3 std::string, and i already know this @KarlKnechtel

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis i'll be on linux, but i can search the runtime methods

Comment: It doesn't matter, you would need a run time system.

Comment: runtime is something i don't know, but i'll search here, thank you

Comment: Why can't you code a bunch of if conditions? You can make a `Sensor` factory that takes a string (or enum) `type`, num `id`, and string `name`, and that returns a `std::unique_ptr<Sensor>`. Going to be `if` statements or `switch` statement though.

Comment: Better question, what makes a `Temperature` sensor different from a `Pressure` sensor? Do they have different interfaces? Different logic? If they have the same interface, just call it a `Sensor` but have a `string type;` to see what kind.

Comment: @JohnFilleau because `std::make_unique<>` requires a type, and i only have the string of the type (I have the string `"Temperature"` fot the type `Temperature`)

Comment: and each sensor does have a specific class, with a specific decoding function

Comment: Is nobody going to mention that `string::push_back` is being passed a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @ZuodianHu what do you mean?

Comment: `sensor` is an `std::string`, no? Then you do `sensor.push_back( std::make_unique<sensor>(...) )`. I don't see how this will compile, since `sensor` is not a type but a variable, and pushing a `unique_ptr` onto a `std::string` doesn't make sense

Comment: "what do you mean?" In the code you have so far, you put `sensor.push_back(std::make_unique<sensor>(01, "test"));`. That is, you used the same name for the thing you want to `push_back` onto (presumably, a vector of unique_ptrs?) as for the type-identifying string.

Comment: "because std::make_unique<> requires a type, and i only have the string of the type" So, write an `if` statement that checks the value of the string, and instantiates the corresponding appropriate type; what's the problem?

Comment: here i done something absurd, i used the same name for  `sensor.push_back` and `std::string sensor`, but i updated it

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
> "because std::make_unique<> requires a type, and i only have the string of the type" So, write an if statement that checks the value of the string, and instantiates the corresponding appropriate type; what's the problem?

because only my config.txt does knows the list of sensors

Comment: @tim does your config.txt have the api and logic of each sensor type as well? You want the user to arbitrarily be able to create new sensor types, is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand. You have a class already written and known at compile-time for each valid type of sensor, correct? If not, then how are you planning to make the new *classes*?

Comment: @JohnFilleau exactly, and the only thing the user will have to code, is the `decoding()` method of the new file, and type `#include something.hpp`  on the main file.

Comment: This link http://derydoca.com/2019/03/c-tutorial-auto-registering-factory/ seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @JohnFilleau oh thank you very much, it seems to be
Gonna try it, and tell if it works on my code, thank you again

Comment: @JohnFilleau this is effectivly the right template (auto registering factory), i can provide the code once finished if needed